# How to store and retrieve an image and description from a database and make it view able by the a set member

Tags: php, mysql

This is a pretty long and hefty question. First off I am new to PHP but I know javascript and HTML as well as CSS. I have created the static elements of a webpage and have managed to integrate it with a login and signup premade php layout, so currently users can signup and login for the site. However the key element remains; the user should be able to select an item from the database and upon selection that item should be "pinned" to a specific div.

e.g. The user clicks on a button below "image.div", when the user clicks on this button a modal pops up with some choices, the user have to select a choice which then loads further information for the user to see. Upon getting this information the user clicks "pin" and the modal closes and that specific choice is "pinned" to "image.div". Each individual "image.div" will have it's own category, e.g. hotels, car rentals, restaurants etc. Ence when selected only the assigned category is displayed by "image.div".

The "pinned" object should only be view able by the user that pinned it when that user logs in.

I also want the choice within the popup modal to be searchable by keywords e.g. kingston, New York etc.

The database that came with the php login scripts have the following table: fgusers
The table has the following columns:  id_user, name, email, phone_number, username and password.

In addition to the above information request I would also like to know how to structure the database for this, should I extend the fgusers table? or should I create separate tables for each?

A response would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then, the best way to achieve the effect you are after is to use AJAX to access database info via a PHP script.  Then use javascript to manipulate the xmlhttp result.

As far as the MySQL database tables go,  it is better to create separate tables for the different information.  You will need to create a column in each table that references an identifying column in the table you want to link that particular tables information to.

Then you just have to use the JOIN commands when referencing the table data.

Example: if you want to link data to specific users you can add a username column to the table and add the users name to the data row.  Later when you want to retrieve that users data,  just reference the users name.  If there are multiple tables of user data, use the JOIN command to link the tables together.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, will report back when I am through